# SQL: how to create two dimensional pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the columns for an employee's month sales summary data records

```
Employee ID  -  Month of Sales   - $ amount
2                Nov 2013            255 
2                Aug 2013            314
15               Jan  2014            86
```

I want the same data, but in two dimensional data table like this

```
   Employee ID  -   Jan 2013   -     Feb 2013   -     Mar  2013
    2                179               122               567 
    3                255               314               789
    4                271               86                213
```

Right now my current idea to write case statements for each month, such as this

```
 (CASE 
 WHEN MONTH = 'JAN 2013' THEN $ AMOUNT 
 ELSE 0 
 END)
 AS JAN 2013
```

The disadvantage to this is that it is not scalable or flexible (Would have to go back each month to add a new month code, plus, if we change the date-encoding format then this query would have to be entirely re-written).

So I am just wondering if y'all know a better way to do this?

Comment: Why are you storing MonthOfSales as character data? It should be datetime. Otherwise you run into all sort of really painful issues.

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL.  The methods are rather different in MySQL and SQL Server, so your question is not really possible to answer.  In any case, you can get an answer by googling "<your database here> dynamic pivot".

Comment: It's not possible to generate *this* result set from *that* data set.

Answer (score -1):

You want to do a dynamic pivot. You can use the STUFF function to grab a list of the Month_of_sales and then create your query with that. Here's how that would look:

```
create table #test (employee_ID int, Month_Of_Sales varchar(50), Amount int)

insert into #test
values (2, 'Nov 2013', 255),
(2, 'Aug 2013', 314),
(15, 'Jan  2014', 86)

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF(
    (SELECT distinct ',['+Month_Of_Sales+']' AS Month_Of_Sales
          FROM #test 
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT Employee_ID, ' + @cols + ' 
from ( select 
   employee_ID, Month_Of_Sales, isnull(Amount,0) as Amount
   from #test 
) as source 
pivot 
( 
sum(Amount) For Month_Of_Sales  in (' + @cols + ')
) as PivotTable'

execute sp_executesql @query;
```